# use a data structure return from c# in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, post, controller

I have a piece of javascript posting to my controller like this:

```
var url = '/Account/getCols';
var formData = { colName: colName }
$.post(url, formdata, function (data, textstatus) {
```

etc...

where Account is the controller getCols is a method within that controller. The method returns a list like so:

```
public List<string> getCols(string colName)
{
    //do some stuff here
    List<string> l = new List<string>;
    //do some more stuff like adding and other manipulation here
    return l;
}
```

How do I use the list when it is returned within my javascript? or should I use some returned Json? or anything else? Sorry, I am rather new to MVC and still looking APIs etc...
Would be grateful for help.

Comment: Serializing it as JSON would be the natural way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializing it as JSON would be the natural way to go. Something like this should do it, if `getCols` is a controller action:

```
public ActionResult getCols(string colName)
{
    //do some stuff here
    List<string> l = new List<string>;
    //do some more stuff like adding and other manipulation here
    return Json(l);
}
```

*If the action is called through HTTP GET, you will have to allow that, since only POST is allowed by default. Something like this:*

```
return Json(l, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```